# /etc/hosts не определяет хост Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, samba, hosts

Не сопоставляется имя и ip адрес в ubuntu 16.04 server. Всё что делал это ковырял конфиг самбы и добавлял юзеров в систему. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
sudo: unable to resolve host servername

sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.1.2       servername

ping -c1 servername
ping: unknown host servername
```

UPD 1:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       r2d2
127.0.1.2       servername

cat /etc/hostname
r2d2

ip a sh scope host
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          iles mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 wins
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

До кучи ещё ошибка:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host r2d2
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу всё содержимое `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, и вывод команды `$ ip a sh scope host`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обновил

Comment: @alexanderbarakin извиняюсь, добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
> ...
> hosts:          iles mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 wins
> ...
> ```

исправьте опечатку: вместо `iles` там явно должно быть `files`